# Google Static maps won't show in facebook messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, google-maps-static-api

Sending this to facebook won't display the map as it used to

```
{
                    "attachment":
                    {
                        "type":"template",
                        "payload":
                        {
                            "template_type":"generic",
                            "elements":
                            [
                                {
                                    "title":"Is this your address?",
                                    "image_url":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C"+address+"&key=API_KEY",
                                    "subtitle":address,
                                    "buttons":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "type":"postback",
                                            "title":"Yes",
                                            "payload":address
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type":"postback",
                                            "title":"No",
                                            "payload":"googlemapwrong"
                                        }              
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
```

Sending other image_url still works but maps aren't displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Abhishek Raj said, Fb is making some kind of double encoding on the url, and then the url doesn't make sense. I have tried to encode the address for url first, but then the address stayed decoded and google didn't recognized it.
the only workaround that I have found is to remove special characters (e.g #,@) from the address if there are any, and replace all the spaces with dashes(google map doesn't mind if you do..)

```
address = address.Replace(' ','-')
```

and then use the address in the url

```
"image_url":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C"+address+"&key=API_KEY"
```

This is working for me on messenger v2.2

Answer (score 0):

It's defined here in [facebook generic template documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template)  that

> horizontal image aspect ratio is 1.91:1 and square image aspect ratio is 1:1
> and
> Aspect ratio used to render images specified by image_url in element objects. Must be horizontal or square. Defaults to horizontal.

So in your case as I see you are trying image size 400*400 which is square. So you can Either

> - try different size of image like 570*300 which is 1.9:1 image ratio

or

> - set image_aspect_ratio inside payload object as square and try your    current image size.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook changed the way they interpret the links I guess the 'address' variable I am concatenating has to to be encoded for urls(spaces should be changed to + or %20 etc.). Facebook was earlier doing this for me but it changed.